# Oracle: How to update every row in a table within the procedure if rows are grouped?

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine I have a table with dublicates (I have simplified the problem and data):
[image]

My procedure with Parent_id as a parametr goes through every row and find value for 'Matched' column in a different table.

It takes about 8 seconds for my procedure to find a value for Matched column. Usually there are thousands of rows. So it takes hours to finish the task.

The problem is that I have to add value to every row I have. Even if those rows are dublicates. If I could group those rows in a cursor, it will save up to 70% of time. But how can I update value of 'Matched' in every single row if `GROUP BY` is used?:
[image]

Comment: how is the format of matched column ? `1,2` in a single row ...?

Comment: It's NUMBER(10)

Comment: So, you want to have 1,2 .  and again 1,2 ... for every repeating duplicate for matched column, don't you?

Comment: I want to group dublicates and put the same 'Matched' value to dublicated rows that were grouped

Comment: How are you updating? It sounds very much like you’re doing it row-by-row, which will be slower than simply using a single update/merge statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use row-by-row update. We recieve dirty data from customers and my procedure finds matched addreess in our database using geographic coordinates.
We send client address to a special web service that returns latitude and longitude,
then my procedure finds an address in our database within 300m radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could simply do an update using the group-by values as a key.

Essentially, for each row returned by the cursor, do something like:

```
UPDATE table SET matched = the_cursor.matched
  WHERE parent_id = the_cursor.parent_id
    AND name = the_cursor.name
    AND address = the_cursor.address
```

For this to be efficient, you would need an index covering at least one of the columns used in the WHERE clause.

But as mentioned in the comments, it all raises the larger question - do you really need to do this row-by-row, or can you use a single MERGE or UPDATE statement to update the entire table?

Comment: Wow, that a great solution! I should have thought about that.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use row-by-row update. We recieve dirty data from customers and my procedure finds matched addreess in our database using geographic coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg()` analytic function as

```
with tab(id,parent_id,name,address ) as
(
 select 1, 1,'Ann' ,'Moscow' from dual union all
 select 2, 1,'Ann' ,'Moscow' from dual union all
 select 3, 1,'Pavel','Tula'  from dual union all
 select 4, 3,'Nikita','Ufa'  from dual union all
 select 5, 3,'Nikita','Ufa'  from dual
)
select parent_id,name,address, to_number(listagg(id) within group (order by id desc)) 
    as matched
  from tab
 group by parent_id,name,address

PARENT_ID   NAME     ADDRESS  MATCHED
 ---------  ------   -------  -------
    1        Ann     Moscow   21
    1        Pavel   Tula     1
    3        Nikita  Ufa      54
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about row_number(). 
But the idea is that Matched value is the same for dublicates.